# I accidentally moved my /lib64. How do I fix this?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

For some stupid reason, I thought it was a good idea to do `sudo mv /lib64 /old_lib64`.
Now I can't do ANYTHING (not opening files, not starting new terminals, not even `ls`).
The only thing I can do now is within this browser which I already have open. (I'm pretty sure if I close it, it won't start again!).

Now what do I do?

Comment: Grab a live linux CD, boot the system with it, `mv /old_lib64 /lib64` ?

Comment: @Darth: post it as an answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you've got a LiveCD for your OS you can boot to that and `mv` it back to its original location

Comment: The machine is running redhat (and I need it to stay redhat), but I don't have a redhat CD. I do have a Ubuntu CD. Would that work?

Comment: Im not sure... I last used RedHat in 2002. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, or grab something generic such as parted magic or knoppix

Comment: Ubuntu (or any other linux live cd) will work fine so long as it has the proper filesystem drivers. If you can see the filesystem, then it should work. (You might have to use `sudo` to elevate to root on Ubuntu)

Comment: actually, I don't see how this is going to work... (no offence intended). The lib has been moved, so even if I logged in as root, I won't be able to run any command, right?

Comment: In other words, `mv` itself might also need some library in `lib64`.

Comment: If you boot off a live CD then the OS and associated commands will be used from there

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The OP used a command to move a folder, I provided a perfectly suitable answer to move it back. I haven't given further detail as I'm sure the OP has the knowledge to move the folder back, but needed the LiveCD hint that a number of others have also added...

Comment: I didn't downvote you (in fact, I upvoted you).

Comment: Sorry One Two Three, I wasn't directing it at you :) You can't see who up/down votes on here so that's why I worded it the way I did.

Comment: Give the disk a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I just reboot the machine from a usb stick, but it doesn't "see" the same directory ...

Comment: @OneTwoThree You will need to mount the host system's harddrive. I think what you're seeing is the LiveCD's `/lib64` folder. You're looking for something like `/media/<drivename>/old_lib64` and you want to move it to `/media/<drivename>/lib64`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/old_lib64" mv /old_lib64 /lib64
```

If you need a terminal, hold ctrl + alt + shift and press 1

Answer (score 0):

This command saved me.

```shell
/old_lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /old_lib64 /usr/bin/cp /old_lib64 /lib64 -fr
```